# Constantly checking if display is working on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-device-driver

Is there a possibility to check if display(monitor) is working or not and to import that data into code? I assume there are some command-line tricks or devices that could 'leak' info about it. Using Linux.

Comment: Something like `xrandr | grep connected`?

Comment: Many thanks! That does the trick :)

Comment: Glad it helped. I've added a longer answer, so you can accept it, if you feel like it. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the X11 extension `XRandR` (*X Resolution and Rotation* or something like that).

You can see the status of output displays with command `xrandr`. In my PC for example you get:

```
$ xrandr | grep connected
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
....
```

The names of the outputs are device specific, of course.

If you want to access the data from a C program, `Xrandr` extension is easy enough to program. This sample code will print the connection status of all the outputs (error checking omitted):

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    Display *dsp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = XRootWindow(dsp, 0);
    XRRScreenResources *sres = XRRGetScreenResources(dsp, root);
    printf("N outputs %d\n", sres->noutput);
    for (int i = 0; i < sres->noutput; ++i)
    {
        XRROutputInfo *info = XRRGetOutputInfo(dsp, sres, sres->outputs[i]);
        printf("  %d: '%s' %s\n", i, info->name, info->connection == RR_Connected ? "connected" : "");
        XRRFreeOutputInfo(info);

    }
    XRRFreeScreenResources(sres);
    XCloseDisplay(dsp);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to get real-time notification of the changes you can use the `XRROutputChangeNotifyEvent` X event, but that will be a bit more complicated: you will need an event loop or use a widget toolkit and hook the X event handler...